# Why does Nina have problems remembering things related to the key?

Tags: locke-and-key

In the Netflix series, Nina seems to forget anything she learns about the keys, or even any events surrounding them, nearly as soon as she learns it.

The Locke children's initial working hypothesis, that it has something to do with age, is clearly wrong. There are plenty of adults who have no trouble remembering details related to the keys, such as Ellie and Mark. Said individuals are not members of the Locke family, so that hypothesis is also hard to sustain.

So why did Nina in particular seem to have serious difficulties remembering anything related to the keys or other magical events?

Comment: https://lockekey.fandom.com/wiki/Riffel_Rule?

Comment: @Valorum - That is clearly the explication for the comics, but it does not apply to the TV series. At least three normal adults remember the effects of the keys while in a normal state of consciousness, including Rendell, apparently. All of them would have entered the Keyhouse through the main door, too, with at least Ellie having entered after turning 18.

Comment: I mean if you're not accepting the comics information doesn't that pretty much make it a question about so-far unrevealed plot elements? Ellie specifically says that she, Mark, and Rendell 'found a way to remember' and it probably has something to do with the scar they all have, but otherwise adults in general don't seem to be able to remember. Why? We'll have to wait till they reveal it.

Comment: @starpilotsixst with a question like this I generally assume there is an implicit 'did I miss something' in the question. Otherwise very few would be answerable without word of God statements from interviews or cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not all the mysteries related to this are revealed, Nina right now seems to be the default situation... that adults, for whatever reason, can't remember the magic, at least while sober (since when she started drinking, she could remember again). There may be some nuances to this rule (for example, it could be that if you played with the keys as a kid you still remember the magic as an adult, but if you're exposed to them as an adult, you just can't remember it while sober) but that seems to be the general gist.

As for Ellie, Mark, and pretty much every other adult we've seen who remembers, they all seem to be deliberate exceptions to the rule, and Ellie hersellf addresses this, although without any firm details:

> Kinsey: How do you remember any of it? The keys, the magic? We thought after you become an adult, you forget.
>
> Ellie: We found a way to remember.

But this was an aside question asked while she was telling a story, and instead of giving more details she simply continues on with a topic unrelated to remembering.

There is a detail that unites them, though, the scars over their chests:

> Nina: You and Rendell have the exact same scar. I know you didn't get it from a bike accident.
>
> Ellie: That's what this is about?
>
> Nina: How'd you get it?
>
> Ellie: We did it to ourselves, okay? Me, Rendell, Mark and Erin... senior year after our friends died, we pressed a hot poker to our chests. It was a way to remember them.

It's almost certain that this story isn't true, or the whole truth at least (since Nina doesn't know any of the details about the keys and there's no reason to tell her any of the magical side) but it does narratively connect the scars to the concept of 'remembering.'

Since they're burn scars, it's possible they used the Matchstick Key somehow and that permanently marking themselves with the key managed to keep their memories. This makes a certain amount of sense, since Nina herself only forgot about the keys magic once she was no longer exposed... she didn't forget the mirror until she was out of the mirror, not while she was still inside it. So, a permanent exposure, a magical burn scar, might leave them forever able to remember. However, it is only speculation.

As for the actual mechanism behind the forgetting, this is thus far unrevealed in the TV series, however the comics does have an explanation that may or may not be used, in whole or in part, [The Riffel Rule](https://lockekey.fandom.com/wiki/Riffel_Rule):

> The Riffel Rule interferes with an adult's perception of magic incurred by the keys. The Rule defines an adult as someone who either reaches the age of 18 or has graduated from High School. Memory of the keys is also disabled by the Rule. It takes effect upon entering Keyhouse Manor through the main door on the west side of the building; this is because the key that enforced the Riffel Rule is the key for the "front door" of Keyhouse.
>
> Another part of the Rule is allowing the Keys to reveal themselves to a child whose heart is free of malice. This was most likely put into place because of 14 year old, John Locke's attempts to use the Keys to participate in WWI because he wanted to "kill some Germans" and do right with the Keys.
>
> The purpose of the rule was to prevent adults from discovering, using, or abusing the powers of the Keys.

Because of this it's probable that adults who see magic and have never visited Keyhouse are immune to the effect and can remember normally, but so far we haven't seen examples of this.